# Updates via FEDERATED engine do not invalidate query cache on remote db?

Tags: mysql

I have two database servers using MySQL 5.5. Server A has table x that is connected via the FEDERATED engine to table y on server B.

If I am directly connected to server A and B and I update x on server A this change should be immediately available on server B but it is not until I reconnect to B.

Is this a known problem or did I misunderstand the FEDERATED engine?

To be more specific:
Server B has table y locally (innodb).
Server A has table x which connects to Server B, table y via federated.

I connect to server A and do an update on table x.
I connect to server B and the change is visible in y.
I do a second update on server A to table x.
I use the same connection to B as before and can't see the second change.
I reconnect to B and can see the second change.

Comment: Transactions? Did you commit the change to x?

Comment: @Marcus Adams: FEDERATED does not support transactions so there is no way to commit.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood. I read your question again and it's a bit ambiguous. Which one has the table locally? The local server can use transactions and does not use Federated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case somebody cares, I found the solution myself: The problem was that I had autocommit switched off on the connection to server B with isolation level set to "CONSISTENT READ".

Since I opened a transaction by selecting some information from B **before** I updated data via FEDERATED I did not see the updated information. After a rollback or commit I was able to see the updated information on B.

So this has nothing to do with FEDERATED nor with query cache as I expected when I asked here.